# Having trouble with grabbing <select> tag focus event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm tearing my hair out right now... I can't figure out how to get a jQuery `$("thing").is(":focus")` selector to work with a `<select>` tag in my code.  Here is what I have:

```
<input id="uText" name="uText" type="text" required/>
<select id="uCarrier" name="uCarrier" style="display: none;"> 
   <option value="NULL" selected="selected">Select One</option>
   <option value="AT&amp;T">AT&amp;T</option>
</select>
```

With this js

```
$("#uText").on("focus", function()
{
    if ( !$("#uCarrier").is(":visible") )
    {
        $(this).stop(true).animate({width:"50%"},400);
        $("#uCarrier").stop(true).hide().delay(400).fadeIn(400);
    }
});


$("#uText").on("blur", function()
{
    if ( !$("#uCarrier").is(":focus") )
    {
        $("#uCarrier").stop(true).fadeOut(400);
        $($("#uText")).stop(true).show().delay( 400 ).animate({width: "96%"}, 400);
    }
});
```

Does anyone out there have a solution to this conundrum??!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `blur` event fires before the focus is shifted to the select element. You can look at the event sequence using the log statements added in the demo fiddle.

One possible solution here is to use `setTimeout` to check the `focus` condition as given below, it delays the execution of the condition for few milliseconds by which the focus would have shifted to the targeted element

```
$("#uText").on("blur", function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        if ( !$("#uCarrier").is(":focus") ){
            $("#uCarrier").stop(true).fadeOut(400);
            $($("#uText")).stop(true).show().delay( 400 ).animate({width: "96%"}, 400);
        }        
    }, 20)    
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4WZMV/)

Answer (score 1):

So here's what's happening on your page:

1. You select the text box.
2. After it's selected, you show the `<select>` with your `onFocus` handler.
3. You click on the `<select>`, which causes two things to happen, in this order:
4. The `<input>` runs its `blur` handler.
5. The `<select>` gains focus.

So Arun is right: you just need to do setTimeout to wait a few milliseconds for the select box to gain focus. :D

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you for explaining the timeline there. It helps!